# Query for all roads and buildings in a province of Belgium_ overpass turbo

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, belgium

I am looking for a query to show all roads and buildings in the province Flemisch Brabant in Belgium.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm assuming that you are asking about how to do this with Overpass since you used that tag. Do you have a partially-working query, or what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using overpass turbo's wizard and the search string *highway or building in "Flemish Brabant"* [this query](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/4I8) has been created (I increased the timeout a little):

```xml
<osm-script output="xml" timeout="250">
  <!-- fetch area “Flemish Brabant” to search in -->
  <id-query {{nominatimArea:Flemish Brabant}} into="area"/>
  <!-- gather results -->
  <union>
    <!-- query part for: “highway” -->
    <query type="node">
      <has-kv k="highway"/>
      <area-query from="area"/>
    </query>
    <query type="way">
      <has-kv k="highway"/>
      <area-query from="area"/>
    </query>
    <query type="relation">
      <has-kv k="highway"/>
      <area-query from="area"/>
    </query>
    <!-- query part for: “building” -->
    <query type="way">
      <has-kv k="building"/>
      <area-query from="area"/>
    </query>
    <query type="relation">
      <has-kv k="building"/>
      <area-query from="area"/>
    </query>
  </union>
  <!-- print results -->
  <print mode="meta"/><!-- fixed by auto repair -->
  <recurse type="down"/>
  <print mode="meta" order="quadtile"/><!-- fixed by auto repair -->
</osm-script>
```

The data is about 270 MB large so better don't try to run and visualize the query in your browser, it won't be able to handle it. Instead use the export button to [download the raw data directly](http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=%3Cosm-script%20output%3D%22xml%22%20timeout%3D%22250%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cid-query%20type%3D%22area%22%20ref%3D%223600058004%22%20into%3D%22area%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3Cunion%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cquery%20type%3D%22node%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chas-kv%20k%3D%22highway%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Carea-query%20from%3D%22area%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fquery%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cquery%20type%3D%22way%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chas-kv%20k%3D%22highway%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Carea-query%20from%3D%22area%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fquery%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cquery%20type%3D%22relation%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chas-kv%20k%3D%22highway%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Carea-query%20from%3D%22area%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fquery%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cquery%20type%3D%22way%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chas-kv%20k%3D%22building%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Carea-query%20from%3D%22area%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fquery%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cquery%20type%3D%22relation%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chas-kv%20k%3D%22building%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Carea-query%20from%3D%22area%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fquery%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Funion%3E%0A%20%20%3Cprint%20mode%3D%22meta%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3Crecurse%20type%3D%22down%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3Cprint%20mode%3D%22meta%22%20order%3D%22quadtile%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fosm-script%3E) or to convert it into a query suitable for Overpass API.